# How to call url to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 page:
page 1 like this

[image]

In page 2. I want after click button it show in current page like this:

[image]

some code of page 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("my_button").click(function(){
//I want show page in page 2 like here images.
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: You must show some html or/and javascript, css

Comment: What question are you asking here?  Are you asking how to overlay the upload UI on top of an existing web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the tool is a page rendered server side 
(ex /uploadtool.php)

load the content of that page in an iframe inside a dialog

example :http://clarkupdike.blogspot.com/2009/03/basic-example-of-jquerys-uidialog.html

Comment: Hi pro...how to show url content in dialog?



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: have a look at the example in http://clarkupdike.blogspot.com/2009/03/basic-example-of-jquerys-uidialog.html and replace www.google.com with your url

Answer (score 2):

Look into [dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). jQuery would be your best option here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="your-upload-div" style="display:none;">
   Your upload window page markup?
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my_button').live("click", function () {
              $('.your-upload-div').show()
              $('.close-btn').hide()
        });
});

</script>
```

Then position it with css.

Pretty sure dialogs would be a good idea here though, I typically use http://fancybox.net/